# Make AsyncTask (or a service) unkillable (or something approaching it)

Tags: java, android, service, kill, dalvik

In my application there's an AsyncTask which runs in the background for much time. The problem is that in low memory situations it's killed by the VM, is there a way to make the application's priority higher, so that it would be harder to kill? Should I use a service instead? My only target is to make it difficult to kill, any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What are you doing that is so resource intensive?  Can you break each request up into smaller requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice you to make it a service and use `startForeground()` which will make it a little more resistant. But even then it might get stopped on low memory.

Comment: thank you for your quick reply, could you explain me why your solution would be better than the AsyncTask?

Comment: If your main Service is resource intensive, you might also want to implement a simple, lightweight Service that only heartbeats the main Service and restarts it as needed.  The idea is that the lightweight service would be less likely to be killed.  In theory, it should work better, but you'd need to test it to see how it works in practice.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no as everyone would abuse this otherwise. If OS kills your service then it got a reason for this. If condition permits and your service qualifies, it will be restarted if Android thinks it shall do so.

Answer (score 0):

If your service is killed, then it's restarted by the system as soon as resources allow.

So, make it a service (it shouldn't be a foreground service, if it doesn't do anything decidedly user-oriented like playing music), but a service that can save its state (`onMemoryLow()` and `onDestroy()` methods). So after the restart it can resume its process with the user being none the wiser.

Comment: Thank you j0ntech, I'll probably take your advice.